# Is there a way to continually keep a few blank lines below where the user inputs in a CLI (terminal) program?

Tags: node.js, unix, command-line-interface

I've a little node program that runs in terminal that asks users for input. After several user responses, the **Make a selection:** is pushed down to the bottom of the terminal.

Visually, I want to have maintain a few lines of space below where a user enters their choice.
I want the person to input as if they are in the center of the terminal.

Is there a technique to do this?

**User input - note: read() is called repeatedly but not shown here:**

```
var  stdin = process.stdin
   , stdout = process.stdout;

function option (answer) {
      // do something with answer 
};

function read () {
    console.log('');
    stdout.write('   \033[33m Make a selection" \033[39m');
    stdin.resume();
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', option);
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this is not a complete answer, but your one stop solution for making CLI programs with node.js is the [commander](https://npmjs.org/package/commander) npm package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeh, I need to look over commander carefully to see if it covers my little visual requirement. Not sure it does. I'll play around with it later to see. I'm pretty sure I'll have to get down to scripting unix.